# Сохранение списка экземпляров класса в базе данных

Tags: c#, база-данных, orm

Есть класс, определяющий модель данных:

```
public class Model
{
   public int id {get; set;}
   public string name {get; set;}

   public void Save()
   {
     using (var db = new DBContext())
     {
         db.Insert(this);
     }
   }
}
```

Чтобы сохранить экземпляр класса Model в БД, можно сделать следующее:

```
Model model = new Model();
model.Save();
```

Можно ли как-нибудь сделать функцию типа:

```
public void Save()
{
    using (var db = new DBContext())
    {
        db.BulkCopy(this); 
    }
}
```

Но чтобы она работала со списком экземпляров класса Model:

```
List<Model> modellist = new List<Model>();
modellist.Save();
```

Comment: Это linq2db? Добавьте метку ORM.

Comment: Как вариант, для того, чтобы сохранять модель в бд, некоторые пишут класс (условно) `DataManager`, который сохраняет/достает данные из бд. Просто создайте такой класс и опишите в нем необходимые методы аля `SaveModels(List<Model> models)`

Comment: Метод расширения можно написать.